# Collision detection with accelerating body in 3D

Tags: math, collision-detection, kinematics

A rigid body has a position, velocity, and radius of a bounding sphere to check for collisions. It is possible to check efficiently if/when two such bodies will collide. This can be done by defining line segments starting at the initial positions and pointing in the direction of the velocities. Then compare the minimal distance between the line segments with the sum of the radii.

See for example [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2213165/find-shortest-distance-between-lines-in-3d#2217845) for a description of the method (there is a difference if the lines are parallel vs skew).

Is there any efficient methods to compute the collision if one of the bodies undergoes a constant acceleration in the time interval of interest?

One conceivable way is to do a collision check with the new velocity vector after having applied the acceleration. If one extends the radius of the obstacle by the length of the acceleration vector, there will be a collision if there is a collision on the actual path taken. However this is an overestimate that does not generalize to longer time intervals as the obstacle radius becomes too large. The idea can be seen in the image, as the distance between the actual path taken 'r(t)' and the linearization through the result veolcity 'v' is bounded by the acceleration vector.
[illustration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qYui9.png)

Comment: There's a word of difference between calculating the minimum distance between two lines and when in the future two rigid bodies will collide.

Comment: That's correct. In the case with zero acceleration though it is possible to find both. A (better?) approach is to subtract the velocity of one body from the other to get a reference frame where one body is considered non-moving. Then the problem reduces to finding the distance between a point and a line segment (rather than two lines). With that setup it is more straightforward to find the time of collision, rather than the line-line distance described above.